# About Tara Mantras

Tags: tara

I am referring to this book: [Исцеляющие мантры в Аюрведе](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%98%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%90%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%20amazon&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwim0ZSa_fnrAhVBPZoKHSgvAXYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%D0%98%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%90%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%20amazon&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CUwwJYk-sCYOLsAmgFcAB4AIABQYgB0AWSAQIxM5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=JXhoX-aqCsH66ASo3oSwBw&bih=1214&biw=1598&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en#imgrc=DqFRlz54pl_GEM).

It is said, that if one chant Tara mantra (bellow), then it opens the fastest way to spiritual perfection.

```
AUM HRIM TRIM HUM PHAT
```

Sorry for maybe wrong spelling as in this book Mantra is written using Cyrillic.

I have got two questions:

1. in the mentioned above book most of the Mantras starts with OM, but some of them starts with AUM. I understand that it is kind of the same syllable (or not?), but why it is written as AUM in some Mantras? Should one pronounce it also as A-U-M while chanting this Mantra, and the other one as O-M? Or should one chant OM? I understand question about different pronunciation of OM or AUM - in different regions can be slightly different, but why it is in written book? It is supposed to be the same syllable OM, isn't it?
2. Would you please write this Mantra for me using Sanskrit?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea why the book uses OM as well as AUM, but they are one and the same. No diffrence in pronunciation occurs. (This is the sanskrit translation: ॐ ह्रीं त्रीं हूं  फट्  ) it looks similar to beeja of Tara devi (ॐ ह्रीं स्त्रीं हूं फट्)

Comment: What is the difference of those two Mantras - the one I wrote and beeja of Tara devi? Do they have the same power and application? Thanks!

Comment: Every beeja although same can produce diffrent results as for each work the way we perform them is diffrent. The power cannot be stated precisely but depends on what sadhana is being performed.